# How do I get json Data from a website into my Xamarin android app

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin

I am trying to get an Array of Json data from a website into an sqlite database on the users phone when he is connected to the internet. I am using the Newtonsoft.json nuget package. Nothing happens when I test it.
This is what i tried

I have a method in the MainActivity that is supposed to read data from the website and then use another method to add the data to a local sqlite database as follows.

```
    public void GetAllPharmacies()
    {
        try
        {

            var client = new HttpClient();
            var uri = "http://no-nonsense-caliber.000webhostapp.com/ajax/GetAllPharmacies.php";
            var result = client.GetStringAsync(uri);
            var pharms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model1>>(result.ToString());
            foreach (Model1 pharm in pharms)
            {
                AddNewPharmacy(pharm.name, pharm.address, pharm.phone, pharm.email, pharm.dp, pharm.gmap, pharm.city);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long);
        }

    }
}

   public class Model1
   {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string dp { get; set; }
    public string gmap { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }

   }

private void AddNewPharmacy(string name, string address, string phone, string email, string dp, string gmap, string city)
    {
        var databasePath = Path.Combine(FilesDir.AbsolutePath, "phidia.db");
        var connectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0}", databasePath);
        SqliteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
        string insertQuery = @"INSERT INTO [Pharmacies] (name,address, phone, email, dp, gmap, city)VALUES (@name,@address, @phone, @email, @dp, @gmap, @city);";
        using (var cmd = new SqliteCommand(insertQuery, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", phone);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dp", dp);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gmap", gmap);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", city);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide complete url to check that url is sending response or not?

Comment: And you expect someone to do what exactly? guess at your problem? write code for you, or just marvel at the lack of detail in this question.. sorry that may have been a bit harsh, but you have to look at this from our perspective

Comment: Sorry...here it is   http://no-nonsense-caliber.000webhostapp.com/ajax/GetAllPharmacies.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to await the GetStringAsync to get a string.   Currently you are getting are trying to deserialize a Task.ToString not what comes back from the site.  It is not good to use async void so I made the function return a boolean.

```
public async Task<bool> GetAllPharmacies()
{
    try
    {

        var client = new HttpClient();
        var uri = "http://no-nonsense-caliber.000webhostapp.com/ajax/GetAllPharmacies.php";
        string result = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
        var pharms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model1>>(result);
        foreach (Model1 pharm in pharms)
        {
            AddNewPharmacy(pharm.name, pharm.address, pharm.phone, pharm.email, pharm.dp, pharm.gmap, pharm.city);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: mscorlib spits out an error 423(). So far I haven't found out why

Comment: 423 Locked: The resource that is being accessed is locked.

Comment: I fixed it. The 423 Error was from the AddNewPharmacy Method not from your answer. I forgot to Open the Sqlite connection. Thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

Follow this article from Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

An example from that site:

```
static async Task<Product> GetProductAsync(string path)
        {

            Product product = null;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
            }
            return product;
        }
```

You can also get the response into a variable and deserialize it with Newtonsoft Json.